# SPSS macro: MultResponse's name and range to come from macro arguments

Tags: macros, spss

I had to make a lot of MRSets, so created these two simple SPSS macros. My question is, is it possible to use macro arguments to define the names ($mrs1) and ranges("1" and "1,9999") of the MRS? The main problem with my current "creation" is that I got 100+ MRSets, all with the same name.

```
define mrcat (
invars=!tokens(100)/
mrsvals=!tokens(1)/
)
MULT RESPONSE GROUPS=$mrs1 (!invars (1,9999))
  /FREQUENCIES=$mrs1.
!enddefine.

define mrdih (
invars=!tokens(100)/
mrsvals=!tokens(1)/
)
MULT RESPONSE GROUPS=$mrs1 (!invars (1))
  /FREQUENCIES=$mrs1.
!enddefine.
```

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested syntax.

```
define !mrcat(mrvar = !tokens(1) /mrsvals = !enclose('"', '"') /invars = !cmdend)
MULT RESPONSE GROUPS = !mrvar (!invars (!mrsvals))
 /FREQUENCIES = !mrvar.
!enddefine.

!mrcat mrvar = $mrs1 mrsvals = "1" invars = v1 v2 v3.
!mrcat mrvar = $mrs2 mrsvals = "1,9999" invars = v1 v2 v3 v4 v5.
```